# How do I copy files off an iPhone using the command line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, iphone

I want to use the command line to access the files on the IPhone instead of using the windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy all the files to my PC.

I've had a look to see if I could map "This PC" or any or the other lines as a network drive but I could not find how.

As per below O intent do copy the lot using the command line, most likely DOS.

[image: This PC on the I phone]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid 3rd-party software, **PowerShell** can use the `shell.application` com object to access virtual folders and MTP devices. Here is a simple copy script:

```
$pcDestinationPath = 'C:\Wherever\You\Want'
$phoneRelativePath = 'Internal Storage\DCIM'

$shell  = New-Object -com shell.application

$PhoneFolder = ($shell.NameSpace("shell:MyComputerFolder").Items() | where Type -match 'Mobile Phone|Portable Device').GetFolder

### To access a subfolder, you have to "walk" its path

$SourceFolder = $phoneRelativePath.Split('\') |
ForEach-Object -Begin {
    $comFolder = $PhoneFolder
} -Process {
    Try
    {
        $comFolder = ($comFolder.Items() | where {$_.IsFolder} | where Name -eq $_).GetFolder
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Error 'Failed to parse $DeviceFolderPath'
    }
} -End {
    $comFolder
}

### Get comFolder object for $pcDestinationPath

If ( ! (Test-Path $pcDestinationPath) )
{
    mkdir $pcDestinationPath -Force | out-null
}
$pcDestinationFolder = $shell.NameSpace($pcDestinationPath)
    
### Option 1: Copy $SourceFolder as a single item

$pcDestinationFolder.CopyHere($SourceFolder.Self)

### Option 2: Copy *the contents of* $SourceFolder as a collection of items

$pcDestinationFolder.CopyHere($SourceFolder.Items())

### Option 3: Copy selected items from $SourceFolder individually

$SourceFolder.Items() | where {<Test-Expression(s)>} |
ForEach-Object {
    $pcDestinationFolder.CopyHere($_)
}  

### FolderItem properties available for testing:
###   - IsFolder
###   - IsLink
###   - ModifyDate
###   - Name
###   - Parent
###   - Path
###   - Size
###   - Type
```

Every directory has both a [Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder) object and a [FolderItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitem) object associated with it. They can reference each other with the `.Self` and `GetFolder` properties:

```
       |--------> Folder.Self ------->|
    Folder                         FolderItem
       |<--- FolderItem.GetFolder <---|
```

References:

- [Shell.NameSpace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace)
- [Folder.Items method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-items)
- [Folder.ParseName method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-parsename)
- [Folder.CopyHere method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere)

Comment: For me the type is 'Portable Device': $PhoneFolder = ($shell.NameSpace("shell:MyComputerFolder").Items() | where Type -eq 'Portable Device').GetFolder ; echo $PhoneFolder.Title
Apple iPhone

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: Thanks for the info. when I wrote this, I was still using a flip phone, not a smartphone (finally gave in last year...). I'll edit the code...

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: Actually, my Pixel 6 identifies as "Mobile Phone", and I see I wrote this in March, so it's a iPhone vs, Android thing...Anyway, updated code to match either type...